# Close dropdown menu on click in angular bootstrap ui

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have dropdown menu on navigation bar shown only for mobile devices. When dropdown menu link is clicked, it just move to another path. As you know, this action will not refresh entire page. But even after i click menu under dropdown, it does not go away.

I want to close the dropdown if the menu link is clicked or when route is changed. How do i do it in angularjs bootstrap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are updating the route on clicking any option of the bootstrap dropdown menu then you can just watch for route change event:

Suppose you have below link which opens up a tooltip.

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle">
  Click me for a dropdown, yo!
</a>

<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li ng-repeat="choice in items" class="ng-scope">
    <a class="ng-binding">The first choice!</a>
  </li><li ng-repeat="choice in items" class="ng-scope">
    <a class="ng-binding">And another choice for you.</a>
  </li><li ng-repeat="choice in items" class="ng-scope">
    <a class="ng-binding">but wait! A third!</a>
  </li>
</ul>

$scope.$on('$routeUpdate', function(scope, next, current) {
   $('html').trigger('click');
});
```

The above will work but there is absolutely no need to grab html element on every route change (as it causes reflow) so better to put it in directive as follows:

```
<html hide-dropdown>

angular.module('App', []).
  directive('hideDropdown', function() {
    return {
       restrict: 'A',
       link: function(scope, element) {
         scope.$on('$routeUpdate', function(scope, next, current) {
           element.trigger('click');
         });
       } 
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks. But it hides the dropdown menu after first click.

Comment: I see. Usually if you click any menu option, it automatically closes the menu - I wonder why its not in your case. I do not think there is an option to hide it other than triggering the click on the html node dynamically as shown in the updated answer.

Comment: In my case, route is based on the hash change.Even when hash of the url changed, will dropdown menu toggle itself? I understand the full page change only reset the dropdown.

Comment: Where am I supposed to put that Javascript?  In a controller?

Comment: @benshope: Yeah, in a controller with respect the problem stated here but you better off with a directive as explained in the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found this work-around useful to close the menu.

```
$scope.$broadcast '$locationChangeSuccess'
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue too, <del>it seems that we can use the `dropdown-toggle` directive.</del>

This is no more working, but with 
angular v1.2.26
angular-ui-bootstrap 0.11.2
Bootstrap v3.2.0
the initial issue seems to be fixed, the drop down menu is closed even if the page is not refreshed.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work (angular 1.2.24, angular-bootstrap 0.11, Bootstrap 3)

Comment: @for3st thanks for pointing that out, you are right, it's no more working